# Multilist With Search in Rendering Parameters is empty

Tags: presentation, fieldtype

It looks like **Multilist With Search** does not work in rendering parameters. No items loaded in list even for very simple query. Is it intentional behavior or there is a way to configure it correctly?

Sitecore 8.1, 8.2

Comment: Just an update on this issue - this has been fixed in 8.2 update 1 and update 2 :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known bug at Sitecore. We had the same problem and created a Sitecore ticket. Please use the reference number 106439 if you contact them.

This is the solution though:

> I was able to reproduce the described behavior in my own environment and have registered this as a bug in the current version of Sitecore.
>   As a workaround for the issue, please perform the following steps:
>   1. Navigate to the **\sitecore\shell\Controls\BucketList** folder and back up the default BucketList.js file.
>   2. Place the attached BucketList.js file instead.
>   3. Clear browser caches.

And here is the contents of the BucketList.js file:

```
var Sitecore = Sitecore || {};

Sitecore.InitBucketList = function (id, clientId, pageNumber, searchHandlerUrl, filter, databaseUrlParameter, typeToSearchString, of, enableSetStartLocation) {
var self = {};

self.id = id;
self.clientId = clientId;
self.pageNumber = pageNumber;
self.searchHandlerUrl = searchHandlerUrl;
self.filter = filter;
self.databaseUrlParameter = databaseUrlParameter;
self.typeToSearchString = typeToSearchString;
self.of = of;
self.enableSetStartLocation = (enableSetStartLocation.toLowerCase() === 'true');

self.currentPage = 1;
self.selectedId = '';

self.doneTypingInterval = 2000; //time in ms, 2 second for example

/*self.contentLanguage = $('scLanguage').value;*/

self.contentLanguage = $('ContentEditorForm').lang;

var typingTimer;

self.format = function (template) {
    var args = arguments;
    return template.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function (m, n) { return args[parseInt(n) + 1]; });
};

// Sends 'GET' request to url specified by parameter
// and apply success handler to multilist element
self.sendRequest = function (url, data, multilist) {
    new Ajax.Request(url,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            parameters: data,
            onSuccess: new self.SuccessHandler(multilist)
        });
};

// Cunstructor for request success handler
self.SuccessHandler = function (multilist) {
    return function (request) {
        var response = eval(request.responseText);
        multilist.options.length = 0;
        multilist.removeClassName('loadingItems');

        var itemIdsHash = {};
        var reducedItems = [];
        var i;
        var item;
        for (i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
            item = response.items[i];

            if (!itemIdsHash[item.ItemId]) {
                itemIdsHash[item.ItemId] = true;
                reducedItems[reducedItems.length] = item;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < reducedItems.length; i++) {
            item = reducedItems[i];
            multilist.options[multilist.options.length] = new Option((item.DisplayName || item.Name) + ' (' + item.TemplateName + (item.Bucket && (' - ' + item.Bucket)) + ')', item.ItemId);
        }

        self.pageNumber = response.PageNumbers;
        self.currentPage = response.CurrentPage;
        $('pageNumber' + self.clientId).innerHTML = self.format(self.of, self.currentPage, self.pageNumber);
    };
};

// Return id of selected item
self.getSelectedItemId = function (controlSuffix) {
    var all = scForm.browser.getControl(self.id + controlSuffix);

    for (var n = 0; n < all.options.length; n++) {
        var option = all.options[n];

        if (option.selected) {
            return option.value;
        }
    }

    return null;
};

self.onFilterFocus = function (filterBox) {
    if (filterBox.value == self.typeToSearchString) {
        filterBox.value = '';
    }

    filterBox.addClassName('active').removeClassName('inactive');
};

self.onFilterBlur = function (filterBox) {
    if (!filterBox.value) {
        filterBox.value = self.typeToSearchString;
    }

    filterBox.removeClassName('active').addClassName('inactive');
};

self.moveToCurrentPage = function () {
    var filterBox = document.getElementById('filterBox' + self.clientId);
    var filterValue = (filterBox.value && filterBox.value != self.typeToSearchString) ? filterBox.value : '*';

    var multilist = $(self.clientId + '_unselected').addClassName('loadingItems');
    var savedStr = encodeURIComponent(filterValue);
    var filterString = self.enableSetStartLocation ? self.getOverrideString('%2Blocation=') : self.filter;
    var selectedIdsFilter = self.getSelectedIdsFilter();

    self.sendRequest(self.searchHandlerUrl, 'fromBucketListField=' + savedStr + "&" + filterString.replace(/\+/g, "%2B") + selectedIdsFilter + '&pageNumber=' + self.currentPage + self.databaseUrlParameter + '&scLanguage=' + self.contentLanguage, multilist);
};

// Replaces overrideKey value in filter by value from ovverrideInput
self.getOverrideString = function (overrideKey) {
    var overrideInput = document.getElementById('locationOverride' + self.clientId);

    if (!overrideInput || !overrideInput.value.length > 0) {
        return self.filter;
    }

    var replaceStartIndex = self.filter.indexOf(overrideKey);

    if (!~replaceStartIndex) {
        return self.filter;
    }

    var replaceEndIndex = self.filter.indexOf('&', replaceStartIndex + 1);

    if (!~replaceEndIndex) {
        replaceEndIndex = self.filter.length;
    }

    var stringToReplace = self.filter.substring(replaceStartIndex, replaceEndIndex);

    return self.filter.replace(stringToReplace, overrideKey + overrideInput.value);
};

self.getSelectedIdsFilter = function() {
    return [].slice.call($(self.clientId + '_selected').options, 0)
        .map(function(option) { return "&-id=" + option.value })
        .join('');
};

self.initEventHandlers = function () {
    $('filterBox' + self.clientId).observe('focus', function () {
        self.onFilterFocus($('filterBox' + self.clientId));
    });

    $('filterBox' + self.clientId).observe('blur', function () {
        self.onFilterBlur($('filterBox' + self.clientId));
    });

    $('filterBox' + self.clientId).observe('keyup', function () {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function () { self.currentPage = 1; self.moveToCurrentPage(); }, self.doneTypingInterval);
    });

    $('filterBox' + self.clientId).observe('keydown', function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    });

    $('next' + self.clientId).observe('click', function () {
        if (self.currentPage + 1 <= self.pageNumber) {
            self.currentPage++;
            self.moveToCurrentPage();
        }
    });

    $('prev' + self.clientId).observe('click', function () {
        if (self.currentPage > 1) {
            self.currentPage--;
            self.moveToCurrentPage();
        }
    });

    $(self.id + '_unselected').observe('dblclick', function () {
        scContent.multilistMoveRight(self.id);
    });

    $(self.id + '_selected').observe('dblclick', function () {
        scContent.multilistMoveLeft(self.id);
    });

    $(self.id + '_unselected').observe('click', function () {
        self.selectedId = self.getSelectedItemId('_unselected');
    });

    $(self.id + '_selected').observe('click', function () {
        self.selectedId = self.getSelectedItemId('_selected');
    });

    $('btnRight' + self.id).observe('click', function () {
        scContent.multilistMoveRight(self.id);
    });

    $('btnLeft' + self.id).observe('click', function () {
        scContent.multilistMoveLeft(self.id);
    });

    $('refresh' + self.clientId).observe('click', function () {
        self.currentPage = 1;
        self.moveToCurrentPage();
    });

    $('goto' + self.clientId).observe('click', function () {
        scForm.postRequest('', '', '', 'contenteditor:launchtab(url=' + self.selectedId + ', la=' + self.contentLanguage + ')');
        return false;
    });
};

var pageNumberElement = $('pageNumber' + self.clientId);
if (pageNumberElement) {
    pageNumberElement.innerHTML = self.format(self.of, self.currentPage, self.pageNumber);
    self.initEventHandlers();
    self.moveToCurrentPage();
}
};
```